# MySQL: selecting unique name, but sum matching columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and can't figure out how to get what I need.  I'm trying to get only the Unique project_id and add all "hours_worked" to each phase_id.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish (see image):

```
project       |  phase1  |  phase 2  |  phase 5  |
"myproject1"  |    0     |     4     |    11.5   |
```

is this possible in one statement?

[image]

Comment: What is RDBMS that you are using (MysQL or whatever)?

Comment: Are the number of phases known in advance, or can there be a variable number of phases by project?

Comment: There will be a set limit, no more than 7

Comment: Just rotate your monitor. Seriously, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why?  because there are several people working on things, possibly in the same stage, but we need a sum of all hours worked per stage.  Not sure what "Just rotate your monitor" means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing from memory:

```
SELECT project_id,
sum(case when phase_id=1 then hours_worked else 0 end),
sum(case when phase_id=2 then hours_worked else 0 end),
sum(case when phase_id=5 then hours_worked else 0 end)
from table_name
group by project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL and the phases are known beforehand, we can risk this:

```
select project_id, 
sum(if(phase_id=1,hours_worked,0)) as phase1,
sum(if(phase_id=2,hours_worked,0)) as phase2,
sum(if(phase_id=3,hours_worked,0)) as phase3,
...
from theTableOfProjects
group by project_id;
```